# Why does my Navbar not stick to the top even tho I gave it the attributes for it?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am lost guys.

I want my Navbar to be sticky to the top but it doenst work and I cant find a solution. Ive tried for so long I gave up and wanted to ask here. I tried the "fixed", t-0, etc. I am using tailwindcss Thanks for any answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-[url('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.753xh;0,0.153xh&resize=1200:*')] h-screen bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat backdrop-blur">
        <nav class="flex absolute fixed top-0 z-10 justify-between h-16 w-full bg-gray-800 px-5 items-center font-semibold text-xl text-white font-sans border-b-4 border-black">
            <div class="w-1/6">
                <a  href="#" class="font-bold">Text1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="space-x-10 ">
                <a href="#" class="p-4 hover:bg-gray-600 active:bg-gray-400">Text1</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 hover:bg-gray-600 active:bg-gray-400">Text1</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 hover:bg-gray-600 active:bg-gray-400">Text1</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 hover:bg-gray-600 active:bg-gray-400">Text1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-1/6">
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="flex z-10 justify-center items-center m-80 pt-5 justify-center font-bold text-white font-sans text-6xl border-4 bg-gray-800 rounded-full border-black">
            <h1>
                Text1
                <p class="p-10 text-4xl">
                    Text1
                </p>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="h-screen w-screen">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/WgQVpNTRUr

here is a tailwind play if anybody needs it.

Comment: Are you using both `absolute` and `fixed` styles to your `nav` element in your real code ?

Comment: I'd have it as an answer where I exchange both of those classes for a single [`sticky`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) but then again I'm not sure if it was just a typo in your post ?

Comment: Thanks it was the sticky attribute. Lov eoyu

Comment: I've moved it into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018902/12737879).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is passing both `absolute` and `fixed` classes to your `nav` element, where instead they should be exchanged for the `sticky` class so that it sticks on top, like:

```
// ..
<nav class="flex sticky top-0 z-10 justify-between h-16 w-full bg-gray-800 px-5 items-center font-semibold text-xl text-white font-sans border-b-4 border-black">
// ..
```

Answer (score 0):

The `backdrop-blur` on the `<body>` element applies a `filter` value, which causes the `<body>` to introduce a new stacking context and stops the `fixed` (I assume you meant this instead of the `absolute` also applied) from working. Removing the `backdrop-blur` should make the navigation bar be fixed to the viewport. See [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SZ1YN8QPrj) for the live example.